# Windows SSH-Agent fails very other time

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-keys

I have stock Windows 11 OpenSSH (not beta) client

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
```

When I interact with SSH every other request fails to find keys/identities in the agent.

```
PS C:\Users\me> ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.

PS C:\Users\me> ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:AuveHTuOTnsAsS9P8di9f0rusOkOGl7rhQ6iZQGm6IE ssh:me(ED25519-SK)
3072 SHA256:FHeoHGky1H+UBGJ6G8BVcNUEFv2q1O4BxHzjck5y76U me@IO-001 (RSA)

PS C:\Users\me> ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.

PS C:\Users\me> ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:AuveHTuOTnsAsS9P8di9f0rusOkOGl7rhQ6iZQGm6IE ssh:me(ED25519-SK)
3072 SHA256:FHeoHGky1H+UBGJ6G8BVcNUEFv2q1O4BxHzjck5y76U me@IO-001 (RSA)

PS C:\Users\me> ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

I have Windows SSH Agent service running.

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

I am quite lost. How do I even investigate it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause and a *solution*.

Turns out it was the effect of GitHub Desktop application being also installed. It seems it comes with its own SSH Agent and SSH client hits either one or the other.

Uninstalling GitHub Desktop solved the issue and now SSH consistently connects to agent which has all the keys.